# Markov chain with finite positive recurrent states

Tags: markov-chains

If I have a Markov chain with finite positive recurrent states $\in S$, then that means starting from a given state $y$, the expected number of steps to return to state $y$ is finite.

Now, if I start at state $j\ne y$ where $y,j\in S$, then I am under the impression that the expected number of steps to reach state $y$ given I start in state $j$ is finite.

I know that state $j$ is positive recurrent too, but I am not sure how to prove the previous statement mathematically?

Comment: I am not sure I know what to *expect to return to state y in finitely many steps* really means. Can you explain?

Comment: It means that if I am at state y, then $E_y (T_y)\lt \infty$ where $T_y=min(n\gt 0:X_n=y)$ is the hitting time for state y. I hope that helped.

Comment: You might want to modify accordingly your question.

Comment: They mean the same thing. In the question I am explaining $E_y(T_y)<∞$ in words.

Comment: No they do not. Actually I might never have seen the phrase *to expect to return to some state in finitely many steps* to mean that the expectation of the return time is finite. Note that if one does return to some state, this is always in finitely many steps.

Comment: Are you familiar with the term "null recurrent"? If a state is null recurrent, then the expected return time is infinite.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7654/discussion-between-solver-and-did)

Comment: No. (Anyway your "Are you familiar" comment is a strong incentive not to.)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the last comment, but I am sorry if you felt offended. I didn't mean to offend you, I was just wondering whether you read about "null recurrence". For me, I wasn't familiar with this term until recently.

BTW, the "let us continue this discussion in chat" sentence was generated automatically when I moved the discussion to the chat section. Sorry if that annoyed you.

Comment: Please feel free to comment if you like, and sorry again for any miscommunication.

Comment: Rather than feeling sorry for this and that and mentioning obvious facts about the "chat" comment, it would be more useful to correct your post.

Comment: I realized that what you said about the two statements being different is correct. I corrected the post above. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Great. Good job. I upvoted the question (and the answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the strong Markov property at $T_j$, and the fact that $y$ is positive recurrent we have
$$\infty>\mathbb{E}_y(T_y)\geq \mathbb{E}_y(T_y\,1_{(T_j<T_y)})
= \mathbb{E}_y([T_y\circ\theta_{T_j}+T_j]\,1_{(T_j<T_y)})$$ $$\geq
 \mathbb{E}_y([T_y\circ\theta_{T_j}]\,1_{(T_j<T_y)})=\mathbb{P}_y(T_j<T_y)\,\mathbb{E}_j(T_y). $$
If it is possible to go from state $y$ to state $j$, then $\mathbb{P}_y(T_j<T_y)>0$ 
and we conclude that $\mathbb{E}_j(T_y)<\infty.$

You *must* assume that the states communicate. For example, if all states are absorbing then they are all positive recurrent, but $\mathbb{E}_j(T_y)=\infty$ for $j\neq y$.

Comment: For this part:
$ℙ_y(T_j\lt T_y)_j(T_y)=_y(T_y1_{(T_j\lt T_y)})\lt \infty$.

Shouldn't it be:
$ℙ_y(T_j\lt T_y)_j(T_y)\le _y(T_y1_{(T_j\lt T_y)})\lt \infty$?

Comment: And thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Solver You are right, that should be an inequality. Apologies!

Comment: This line of reasoning works for a countably infinite state space, correct? I do not see why $\mathbb{E}_y[T_y] \ge \mathbb{E}_y[T_y 1_{T_j < T_y}]$. Say $\mathbb{E}_y[T_y] = 10$, and state $j$ is at least 20 steps away from state $y$, then is $\mathbb{E}_y[T_y 1_{T_j < T_y}] \ge 20$? Can you explain the notation $[ T_y \circ \theta_{T_j} + T_j ]$ please? Thank you!

Comment: The random variables satisfy the pointwise inequality $T_y\geq T_y\,1_{\{T_j<T_y\}}$, since the indicator function only takes the values 0 and 1.

Comment: @Ritz  $\theta$ is the shift operator, so $T_j+T_y\circ\theta_{T_j}=\inf(t≥T_j:X_t=y)$, the first time after hitting state $j$ that the process hits state $y$.